# AVAssetReader audio capture, samples missing

Tags: cocoa, avfoundation, avassetreader

I've a weird question. I'm capturing some audio samples of a .mov/.wav/.aiff files to playback them.
I'm using the following codes that captures unchanged PCM samples if available , otherwise convert them to 32 bit float.

```
NSError *error = nil;
AVAssetReader *assetReader= [[[AVAssetReader alloc] initWithAsset:self.movieAsset error:&error] autorelease];
NSArray *audioTracks=[movieAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio];
AVAssetReaderTrackOutput* audioReaderOutput=nil;
AVAssetTrack *mainAudioTrack = nil;
CMTimeRange audioRange;
if ([audioTracks count]) {
    mainAudioTrack=[audioTracks objectAtIndex:0];
    audioRange = mainAudioTrack.timeRange;
    CMTimeRange readingRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero,audioRange.duration);
    assetReader.timeRange = readingRange;
    NSArray* formatDesc = mainAudioTrack.formatDescriptions;
    if ([formatDesc count]) {
        CMAudioFormatDescriptionRef item = (CMAudioFormatDescriptionRef)[formatDesc objectAtIndex:0];
        const AudioStreamBasicDescription* pcmAudioDescription = CMAudioFormatDescriptionGetStreamBasicDescription (item);
        NSDictionary * outputSettings;
        memcpy(&audioDescription,pcmAudioDescription,sizeof(AudioStreamBasicDescription));

        if (pcmAudioDescription->mFormatID != kAudioFormatLinearPCM ) {

            // Resample
            outputSettings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                              [NSNumber numberWithInt:kAudioFormatLinearPCM], AVFormatIDKey,
                              [NSNumber numberWithFloat:pcmAudioDescription->mSampleRate], AVSampleRateKey,
                              [NSNumber numberWithInt:pcmAudioDescription->mChannelsPerFrame], AVNumberOfChannelsKey,
                              [NSNumber numberWithInt:32], AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey,
                              [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], AVLinearPCMIsFloatKey,
                              nil];

            audioDescription.mFormatID = kAudioFormatLinearPCM;
            audioDescription.mBitsPerChannel = 32;
            audioDescription.mFramesPerPacket = 1;
            audioDescription.mChannelsPerFrame = pcmAudioDescription->mChannelsPerFrame;
            audioDescription.mBytesPerFrame = audioDescription.mBitsPerChannel / 8 * audioDescription.mChannelsPerFrame;
            audioDescription.mBytesPerPacket = audioDescription.mFramesPerPacket * audioDescription.mBytesPerFrame;
            audioDescription.mFormatFlags = kAudioFormatFlagIsFloat;

        } else {

            outputSettings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                              [NSNumber numberWithInt:kAudioFormatLinearPCM], AVFormatIDKey,
                              nil];

            audioDescription.mFormatID = kAudioFormatLinearPCM;
        }

        audioReaderOutput=[[[AVAssetReaderTrackOutput alloc]
                            initWithTrack:mainAudioTrack
                            outputSettings:outputSettings] autorelease];
        if([assetReader canAddOutput:audioReaderOutput]) [assetReader addOutput:audioReaderOutput];
        else audioReaderOutput = nil;

    }

}

if (audioReaderOutput) {
    if([assetReader startReading]==YES){
        CMSampleBufferRef buffer = 0;
        NSTimeInterval duration = 0.0;

        while([assetReader status]==AVAssetReaderStatusReading){
            if (audioReaderOutput != nil) {
                buffer=[audioReaderOutput copyNextSampleBuffer];
                if (buffer) {
                    CMTime sampleDuration = CMSampleBufferGetDuration (buffer);
                    CMTime currentSampleTime = CMSampleBufferGetOutputPresentationTimeStamp (buffer);
                    MovieSample* sample = [[[MovieSample alloc] init] autorelease];
                    sample.sampleTime = currentSampleTime;
                    sample.sampleBuffer = buffer;
                    sample.sampleDuration = sampleDuration;
                    [self.audioStore addObject:sample];
                    //NSLog(@"Adding sample %lld %lld %f %f",currentSampleTime.value,sampleDuration.value,currentOutputSampleTime.value/(NSTimeInterval)currentOutputSampleTime.timescale,
                         // (currentOutputSampleTime.value+sampleDuration.value)/(NSTimeInterval)currentOutputSampleTime.timescale);
                    NSLog(@"Received PCM buffer with [TIMESTAMP:%.1fms]", CMTimeGetSeconds(currentSampleTime) * 1000);
                    NSLog(@"Buffer contains [SAMPLES:%ld]", CMSampleBufferGetNumSamples(buffer));
                    NSLog(@"Buffer contains [DURATION:%.1fms] worth of audio", CMTimeGetSeconds(sampleDuration) * 1000);
                    duration += CMTimeGetSeconds(CMSampleBufferGetDuration(buffer));
                }

            }

        }
        NSLog(@"Total samples duration: %f", duration);
        NSLog(@"Total track reported duration: %f", audioRange.duration.value/(NSTimeInterval)audioRange.duration.timescale);

    }
    else {
        DLog(@"could not start Audio reading asset.");
        DLog(@"reader status: %ld", [assetReader status]);
    }


}
```

Now the weird thing is that, no matter what file I open, it always miss some samples at the of the file. 
The following loop http://www.vvertex.com/loop.wav has a duration reported as 3.75 either from Audacity and from the audio track duration, mainAudioTrack.timeRange, while the dump of my code that prints the samples length and playing offset is: 3.657120

This is the dump:

2014-03-06 10:48:15.721 FrameDecoder[665:303] Received PCM buffer with [TIMESTAMP:0.0ms]
2014-03-06 10:48:15.721 FrameDecoder[665:303] Buffer contains [SAMPLES:8192]
2014-03-06 10:48:15.721 FrameDecoder[665:303] Buffer contains [DURATION:185.8ms] worth of audio
2014-03-06 10:48:15.721 FrameDecoder[665:303] Received PCM buffer with [TIMESTAMP:185.8ms]
2014-03-06 10:48:15.721 FrameDecoder[665:303] Buffer contains [SAMPLES:8192]
2014-03-06 10:48:15.721 FrameDecoder[665:303] Buffer contains [DURATION:185.8ms] worth of audio
2014-03-06 10:48:15.722 FrameDecoder[665:303] Received PCM buffer with [TIMESTAMP:371.5ms]
2014-03-06 10:48:15.722 FrameDecoder[665:303] Buffer contains [SAMPLES:8192]
2014-03-06 10:48:15.722 FrameDecoder[665:303] Buffer contains [DURATION:185.8ms] worth of audio
2014-03-06 10:48:15.722 FrameDecoder[665:303] Received PCM buffer with [TIMESTAMP:557.3ms]
2014-03-06 10:48:15.722 FrameDecoder[665:303] Buffer contains [SAMPLES:8192]
2014-03-06 10:48:15.722 FrameDecoder[665:303] Buffer contains [DURATION:185.8ms] worth of audio
2014-03-06 10:48:15.723 FrameDecoder[665:303] Received PCM buffer with [TIMESTAMP:743.0ms]
2014-03-06 10:48:15.723 FrameDecoder[665:303] Buffer contains [SAMPLES:8192]
2014-03-06 10:48:15.723 FrameDecoder[665:303] Buffer contains [DURATION:185.8ms] worth of audio
2014-03-06 10:48:15.723 FrameDecoder[665:303] Received PCM buffer with [TIMESTAMP:928.8ms]
2014-03-06 10:48:15.726 FrameDecoder[665:303] Buffer contains [SAMPLES:8192]
2014-03-06 10:48:15.726 FrameDecoder[665:303] Buffer contains [DURATION:185.8ms] worth of audio
2014-03-06 10:48:15.727 FrameDecoder[665:303] Received PCM buffer with [TIMESTAMP:1114.6ms]
2014-03-06 10:48:15.727 FrameDecoder[665:303] Buffer contains [SAMPLES:8192]
2014-03-06 10:48:15.727 FrameDecoder[665:303] Buffer contains [DURATION:185.8ms] worth of audio
2014-03-06 10:48:15.727 FrameDecoder[665:303] Received PCM buffer with [TIMESTAMP:1300.3ms]
2014-03-06 10:48:15.727 FrameDecoder[665:303] Buffer contains [SAMPLES:8192]
2014-03-06 10:48:15.727 FrameDecoder[665:303] Buffer contains [DURATION:185.8ms] worth of audio
2014-03-06 10:48:15.727 FrameDecoder[665:303] Received PCM buffer with [TIMESTAMP:1486.1ms]
2014-03-06 10:48:15.728 FrameDecoder[665:303] Buffer contains [SAMPLES:8192]
2014-03-06 10:48:15.728 FrameDecoder[665:303] Buffer contains [DURATION:185.8ms] worth of audio
2014-03-06 10:48:15.728 FrameDecoder[665:303] Received PCM buffer with [TIMESTAMP:1671.8ms]
2014-03-06 10:48:15.728 FrameDecoder[665:303] Buffer contains [SAMPLES:8192]
2014-03-06 10:48:15.728 FrameDecoder[665:303] Buffer contains [DURATION:185.8ms] worth of audio
2014-03-06 10:48:15.728 FrameDecoder[665:303] Received PCM buffer with [TIMESTAMP:1857.6ms]
2014-03-06 10:48:15.729 FrameDecoder[665:303] Buffer contains [SAMPLES:8192]
2014-03-06 10:48:15.729 FrameDecoder[665:303] Buffer contains [DURATION:185.8ms] worth of audio
2014-03-06 10:48:15.729 FrameDecoder[665:303] Received PCM buffer with [TIMESTAMP:2043.4ms]
2014-03-06 10:48:15.729 FrameDecoder[665:303] Buffer contains [SAMPLES:8192]
2014-03-06 10:48:15.729 FrameDecoder[665:303] Buffer contains [DURATION:185.8ms] worth of audio
2014-03-06 10:48:15.729 FrameDecoder[665:303] Received PCM buffer with [TIMESTAMP:2229.1ms]
2014-03-06 10:48:15.730 FrameDecoder[665:303] Buffer contains [SAMPLES:8192]
2014-03-06 10:48:15.730 FrameDecoder[665:303] Buffer contains [DURATION:185.8ms] worth of audio
2014-03-06 10:48:15.730 FrameDecoder[665:303] Received PCM buffer with [TIMESTAMP:2414.9ms]
2014-03-06 10:48:15.730 FrameDecoder[665:303] Buffer contains [SAMPLES:8192]
2014-03-06 10:48:15.730 FrameDecoder[665:303] Buffer contains [DURATION:185.8ms] worth of audio
2014-03-06 10:48:15.731 FrameDecoder[665:303] Received PCM buffer with [TIMESTAMP:2600.6ms]
2014-03-06 10:48:15.731 FrameDecoder[665:303] Buffer contains [SAMPLES:8192]
2014-03-06 10:48:15.731 FrameDecoder[665:303] Buffer contains [DURATION:185.8ms] worth of audio
2014-03-06 10:48:15.731 FrameDecoder[665:303] Received PCM buffer with [TIMESTAMP:2786.4ms]
2014-03-06 10:48:15.731 FrameDecoder[665:303] Buffer contains [SAMPLES:8192]
2014-03-06 10:48:15.731 FrameDecoder[665:303] Buffer contains [DURATION:185.8ms] worth of audio
2014-03-06 10:48:15.732 FrameDecoder[665:303] Received PCM buffer with [TIMESTAMP:2972.2ms]
2014-03-06 10:48:15.732 FrameDecoder[665:303] Buffer contains [SAMPLES:8192]
2014-03-06 10:48:15.732 FrameDecoder[665:303] Buffer contains [DURATION:185.8ms] worth of audio
2014-03-06 10:48:15.732 FrameDecoder[665:303] Received PCM buffer with [TIMESTAMP:3157.9ms]
2014-03-06 10:48:15.732 FrameDecoder[665:303] Buffer contains [SAMPLES:8192]
2014-03-06 10:48:15.733 FrameDecoder[665:303] Buffer contains [DURATION:185.8ms] worth of audio
2014-03-06 10:48:15.733 FrameDecoder[665:303] Received PCM buffer with [TIMESTAMP:3343.7ms]
2014-03-06 10:48:15.733 FrameDecoder[665:303] Buffer contains [SAMPLES:8192]
2014-03-06 10:48:15.733 FrameDecoder[665:303] Buffer contains [DURATION:185.8ms] worth of audio
2014-03-06 10:48:15.733 FrameDecoder[665:303] Received PCM buffer with [TIMESTAMP:3529.4ms]
2014-03-06 10:48:15.734 FrameDecoder[665:303] Buffer contains [SAMPLES:5631]
2014-03-06 10:48:15.734 FrameDecoder[665:303] Buffer contains [DURATION:127.7ms] worth of audio
2014-03-06 10:48:15.734 FrameDecoder[665:303] Total samples duration: 3.657120
2014-03-06 10:48:15.734 FrameDecoder[665:303] Total track reported duration: 3.750000

Anyone ever faced a strange issue like this ? I've tried several audio files as well as .mov files with different compressions. Same stuff ! I'm totally stuck on this !

Also when I play the samples through AudioUnits, it seams that what's effectively missing is that from the beginning of the sample....

Thanks !

Comment: additional note, the AVReaderWriterOSX sample has the same issue, it mangles the initial part of the audio sample! Does this mean AVAssetReader is not good to rip audio samples ???

Answer (score 0):

my workaround...

```
//starting 2 buffers before
[_reader setTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(CMTimeMake(-16384, samplerate), kCMTimeNegativeInfinity)];

//and
while ([_reader status] == AVAssetReaderStatusReading) {
    CMSampleBufferRef sampleBufferRef = [_ringBufferReaderTrackOutput copyNextSampleBuffer];
    if (sampleBufferRef){
        CMTime t = CMSampleBufferGetOutputPresentationTimeStamp(sampleBufferRef);
        if( t.value < 0 )
            release, continue...
    }
```

but i am missing 4096 samples on end :-(

Comment: Yeah Apple told me that the AVAssetReader is bugged :/ Actually I spawn a 32 bit quicktime helper that rips the Audio and send it back through an NSConnection XPC..

Comment: @LeonardoBernardini I believe I'm running into the same issue: When reading a 30-FPS mp4 file with `AVAssetReader`, it never outputs the last frame of video from the file. Additionally, it interprets the first frame's timestamp as 0.033333 instead of 0, which seems odd to me. Did you file a bug report with Apple? Did they happen to provide any workarounds?

Comment: I haven't found missing samples from the video, just the audio. I've tried an H264 .mov file with success but not an mp4. By the way, Apple guys did not provide me with a solution, they also pushed back my ticket as "available" ! (Hands washed!)

Comment: A little more detail on my issue: I was able to solve it by re-encoding my input video file as QuickTime H.264. The video that `AVAssetReader` struggled with was an mp4 file in the "AVC Coding" format, which is apparently synonymous with H.264. Maybe `AVAssetReader` simply didn't like the mp4 because it wasn't in a QuickTime container?

Comment: didn't you had problems with the Audio or you're dealing just with Video ? I had no problem with the H264...